# Heat Sink Effect in Burned Out Cooldown

Tags: ingress

Does Heat Sink affects the cooldown of portal burned out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heat Sink only lowers the 5-minute cooldown, you still have to wait the four hours between hacking sessions.